# How to implement default behavior with a using macro?

Tags: elixir, abstract-syntax-tree

I have a behavior module and an implementation for use in production. During testing, I want to override some of the behavior callbacks with a stub or mock. This code and the embedded comments illustrate the problem:

```
defmodule BehaviorApi do
  @callback foo(integer()) :: {:ok, String.t()}
end

defmodule MyDefaultApiImplementation do
  @behaviour BehaviorApi
  def foo(num), do: {:ok, "foo-#{num}"}
end

defmodule Api do
  defmacro __using__(_opts) do
    defaults =
      Enum.map(MyDefaultApiImplementation.__info__(:functions), fn {func_atom, func_arity} ->
        quote do
          # HOW TO WRITE THIS TO ACCOUNT FOR ARITY?
          defdelegate unquote(func_atom), to: MyDefaultApiImplementation
          defoverridable([{unquote(func_atom), unquote(func_arity)}])
        end
      end)

    beh =
      quote do
        @behaviour BehaviorApi
      end

    [beh | defaults]
  end
end

defmodule MyOverrideApi do
  use Api ## COMPILE ERROR HERE: (ArgumentError) invalid syntax in defdelegate :foo
end
```

How can I write the body of the `__using__` macro so that it synthesizes the correct `defdelegate` regardless of the arity of the function?

Comment: you are complicating the problem, instead use the config to specify the required module implmentation.

Comment: @Daniel For sure, there are multiple ways to approach the problem I'm having. Putting the module name in the config will require every variation of the API  implementation (there may be many due to tests' different needs) to implement every callback. This is what I am trying to avoid by having a default, overridable implementation.

Answer (score 0):

There are certainly many ways of approaching this. Sometimes I find that some solutions feel a bit more like "pushing the river" than others -- even though they might make good sense, their actual implementations are more difficult than alternatives.

Because you are using behaviours with implementations and your concern surrounds tests, I would lean into the [`Mox`](https://hexdocs.pm/mox/Mox.html) package, in particular its [`stub_with/2`](https://hexdocs.pm/mox/Mox.html#stub_with/2) function.  Mox is designed to have the effect of "fabricating" a module at runtime.

In your case, you might set up a virtual `MockAPI` of your `BehaviorApi` module and stub it with whatever defaults you have defined for `MyDefaultApiImplementation` like so:

```
# test/test_helper.exs
ExUnit.start()

Mox.Server.start_link([])

defmock(MockAPI, for: BehaviorApi)
stub_with(MockAPI, MyDefaultApiImplementation)
```

Your tests can then "override" (i.e. "mock") specific functions using [`Mox.expect/4`](https://hexdocs.pm/mox/Mox.html#expect/4)

```
test "something" do
  # Here we mock the get/2 function, so the provided callback must accept 2 args
  api =
    MockAPI
    |> expect(:get, fn _, _ ->
      {:ok, "some response"}
    end)

  assert {:ok, "some response"} = api.get(nil, nil)
end
```

Chances are your real implementation is more complex (e.g. because maybe you are not calling the API functions directly), so a common pattern is to "inject" the needed module as a function argument.

For example, if you have a helper that calls the API and then processes the result, you might need to adjust your function inputs to allow for easier testing.  E.g. you might need to modify something like this:

```
defmodule Foo
  def get(x) do
    MyApi.do_something(x)
    |> some_processing_here()
    # ... 
  end
end
```

to something like this:

```
defmodule Foo
  def get(x, opts \\ []) do
    api = Keyword.get(opts, :api, MyApi)
    api.do_something(x)
    |> some_processing_here()
    # ... 
  end
end
```

so that your test can "inject" the mock via something like

```
  api =
    MockAPI
    |> expect(:do_something, fn _ ->
      {:ok, "some response"}
    end)

  Foo.get(123, api: api)
```

These are only suggestions, but I think Mox may meet your needs.